# Text or Google Fonts are not showing in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, google-font-api, visual-composer

some users of our site ([Link](http://fba-hero.com)) that are using chrome say that the text blocks aren't showing on the site for some reason.

I use Chrome too and everything works fine. I attached a picture of the problem below.

Hope somebody can help fix that problem.

Text blocks aren't displayed:

[image: Text blocks aren't displayed]

Comment: In my pc is it show fine. @tymz96

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a fallback font-family on your elements which does not already have it.

When I inspect one of your h1 tags I can see that the font-family is set to the following:

```
font-family: "Fira Sans";
```

Try to set that to:

```
font-family: "Fira Sans", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
```

As you have it on your body tag.

Apply this to all the elements which does not already have a fallback font.

Let me know if it solves the problem :)